# Android multiple record SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, loops, record

I saw in the SQLite documentation that you can not insert multiple records at the same time. For example, I have `2 TEXT fields` and at the same time I want to insert in filed1 `10 records` with the `date` that goes from today to 10 days, and in the `field2` value of `50 was added in the 10 record`. I hope I explained.
Now normally I insert the record in this way:

```
public void insertDb(View v) {
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(Table.ONE, mNe.getText().toString());
cv.put(Table.ONE, mNel.getText().toString());
...
```

Comment: add your full code so any one can check what are you doing

Comment: still do not have anything beyond that. I wanted to know what is the best way to obtain this result or if you have examples to me. thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please explain your need or add relevant code

Comment: Is there a question here? You know you just need to use a loop right?

Comment: If you want to insert multiple records at time than use sqlite transaction

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to use for loop or anything

like below code

```
public void add_device(String data,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist) {

    try {

        database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        for (HashMap<String, String> map : jsonlist) {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(SAVE_COLUMN_NAME, data);
            values.put(SAVE_COLUMN_KEY, map.get(SAVE_COLUMN_KEY));
            values.put(SAVE_COLUMN_VALUE, map.get(SAVE_COLUMN_VALUE));
            Long int1 = database.insertOrThrow(SAVE_TABLE_NAME, null,
                    values);
            Log.i("inserted value", values + "");
            Log.i("insserted value ", int1 + "");
        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

you can use loop like i have used

Comment: For clarity, I'd refactor the code to insert a single row into its own method, and then call that from the loop.